# How can I translate routes in ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, internationalization, ember-cli, translate

I created some routes in app/router.js

```
Router.map(function () {
    let i18n = this.service('i18n');
    this.route("lang", { path: '/:lang' }, function () {
        this.route('home', { path: '/', template: 'home' });
        this.route('about', { path: '/' + i18n.t('router.about'), template: 'about' });
        this.route('locales', { path: '/' + i18n.t('router.locations'), template: 'locales' });
    });
});
```

But the i18n translates only the first time.

How can I translate these routes by change language?

I'm using:

ember-cli: 2.11.1

node: 7.4.0

[ember-i18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n): 5.0.0

Comment: Please read this page: http://xyproblem.info , then carefully describe what you're willing to achieve. What you're doing is very wrong, so I want to hear your original goal, not your intended approach on achieving it.

Comment: Do you want to translate the route names in the URL? If yes, don't! This is a *really* bad idea.

Comment: @Lux, I'm trying to translate the route path.

Comment: This is not possible. Use english names for your path.

Answer (score 0):

The routes created once and you can not change the route names.

For your goal you can do like :

```
//router.js

this.route("lang", {path: '/:lang'}, function() {
    this.route('register', {path: ':path'});
  });
```

And in template :

```
//index.hbs
{{#link-to "lang.register" locale path}}{{t "routes.register"}}{{/link-to}}
```

and in corresponding controller :

```
//controllers/index.js
i18n: Ember.inject.service(),

  locale: Ember.computed.readOnly('i18n.locale'),

  path: Ember.computed('locale', function() {
    return {
      path: this.get('i18n').t('routes.register')
    };
  }),
```

Now your url of routes changed based on `i18n` locales change.

Please take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2e5231b82995770ed547f70b34bfbebb)

Comment: But, how can I change the current URI in the same time?

Comment: @BrunoSalgado I updated my twiddle. Please take a look at `changeLang` action

Comment: Ebrahim, this works fine. But, when I use more than one route, Ember always calls the first route defined. It's 'cause the path is dynamic (path: '/:path'). Can you help me please? [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/307a4a1e767d6feee843a10c87c443d8?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C&route=%2Fen%2Fhome)

Comment: @BrunoSalgado Thta problem is because of routes overlaps in names. I provide solution in [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/342a251605a39ebb6bce6e110ec41343?openFiles=helpers.route-param.js%2C&route=%2Fen%2Fhome)

Comment: Can I load the application by a language and route coming from the URI? Example: The user directly accesses the pt-br/sobre path.

Comment: @BrunoSalgado Yes you can

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: @BrunoSalgado It is out of the scope of this question. It's better to post a new question. Also please provide a twiddle to say what do you want